# Sequelize: Joining a max version record associated table?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In my application, I have two models `user` and `userdetail`. `user` detail is simply a table containing a unique ID, and `userdetail` has a unique key on `(user_id, version)`. When I want to get the latest user data, I run SQL similar to the following:

```
SELECT userdetail1.password_hash FROM user
JOIN userdetail userdetail1 ON userdetail1.user_id = user.id
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(version) version
    FROM userdetail
    GROUP BY user_id
) userdetail2 ON userdetail2.user_id = userdetail1.user_id AND userdetail2.version = userdetail1.version
WHERE user.id = 1;
```

The database I am working on only allows INSERTs, so I can only 'update' records by inserting a new row into `userdetail`.

I have defined two models in Sequelize:

```
var UserDetail = sequelize.define('userdetail', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: 'user',
            key: 'id'
        }
    },
    version: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
        allowNull: false
    },
    password_hash: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'userdetail'
});
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    created: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'user'
});
User.hasMany(UserDetail.getModel(), {
    foreignKey: "user_id"
});
UserDetail.getModel().belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: "user_id"
});
```

I wish to find the latest record using the findAll() method. This is where I am running into problems. I know I need to join three times (User <-> UserDetail <-> UserDetail), so I have the following:

```
return this.model.findAll({
    include: [{
    model: this.UserDetail.getModel()
}, {
    model: this.UserDetail.getModel(),
    as: "userdetail2"
}]
```

However, this gives the error `userdetail (userdetail2) is not associated to user!`, so I am not sure how to join the same table twice?

Furthermore, I need the second join to have a condition on `userdetail.version` in its `ON` clause -- is this possible in Sequelize?

Answer (score 3):

Another variant to the answers above:

merge in a literal statement This is using T-SQL. The idea is that you join but only with the max result of the version field.

```
db.user.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: db.userDetail,
      as: 'userdetail_a',
      where: {
       userId: userId,
       [Op.and]: [ Sequelize.literal(' version = (
         Select MAX(version)
         FROM tbluserDetail 
         WHERE
         userId = [user].[userId])')
       ],
      }
    }
  ],
});
```

you have to set the association of 'userdetail_a' as hasOne even though there is many otherwise your join ends up as one value in an array

Answer (score 1):

You should do the association two times as well:

```
User.hasMany(UserDetail.getModel(), {
    foreignKey: "user_id"
});
User.hasMany(UserDetail.getModel(), {
    as: "userdetail2",
    foreignKey: "user_id"
});
UserDetail.getModel().belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: "user_id"
});
UserDetail.getModel().belongsTo(User, {
    as: "userdetail2",
    foreignKey: "user_id"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for the answer to this, I answered it in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8600

First step is to declare the one-to-many association twice, as suggested by @Adam.

Then the query would look like this:

```
db.user.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: db.userDetail,
      required: false, // forces left join
      duplicating: false // prevents sub-queries
    },
    {
      model: db.userDetail,
      as: 'userdetail2',
      required: false, // forces left join
      duplicating: false, // prevents sub-queries
      on: {
        '$user.id$': { $col: 'user->userdetail2.userId' },
        '$user->userdetail.version$': { $col: 'user->userdetail2.version' }
      }
    }
  ],
  where: {
    '$user->membership_2.id$': { $eq: null }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let users = await User.findAll({
  where,
  // order: [
    //     [body.sort.key, body.sort.value]
  // ],
  include: [{
    model: ProgramInformation,
    as: "program_info",
    attributes: ["program_id", "user_id", "coach_id", "referral_date", "next_appointment"],
    required: body.user_status != -1 ? true : false,
    // where: {
      //  coach_id: {
        //  [Op.eq]: body.company_id
      //  }
    // },
    include: [{
      model: ProgramDemographic,
      as: "demographic_info",
      where: {
        user_status: body.user_status
      },
      required: body.user_status != -1 ? true : false,
      order: [
        ["createdAt", "DESC"]
      ]
    }, {
      model: User,
      as: "coach_detail",
      attributes: ["user_id", "name", "first_name", "last_name"],
    },],
  }, {
    model: ProgramStatusLog,
    as: "program_status_log",
    [Op.and]: [Sequelize.literal('changed_program_status = ' + body.changed_program_status), Sequelize.literal('program_status_id = (Select MAX(program_status_id) FROM program_status_log WHERE userId = user.user_id)')],
    required: body.changed_program_status != -1 ? true : false,
  }, {
    model: UserMood,
    as: "user_mood",
    where: {
      date: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    },
    attributes: ["mood_id", "user_id"],
    required: false,
    include: [{
      model: MasterMood,
      as: "mood_details",
      attributes: { exclude: ["createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt"] },
      required: false,
    }],
  }, {
    model: ProgramReferralInfo,
    as: "program_referral_info",
    attributes: ['referral_body', 'referral_type'],
    require: false,
    include: [{
      model: MasterReferralBody,
      as: "referralbody",
      attributes: ["referral_body"]
    }]
  }],
  order: [
    [
      { model: ProgramStatusLog, as: "program_status_log" },
      sequelize.col("program_status_id"),
      "desc",
    ],
  ],
  limit: body.limit ? body.limit : 25,
  offset: body.offset ? body.offset : 0,
});
```